# Register channel with known name, then check and unregister it through that known name without terminate other application channel

Tags: c#, .net, tcp, remoting

i had problem with application messaging, ...after some question and answer, i went to use Remoting namespace, under System.Runtime namespace...

it worked perfectly, but the matter is when application terminate with exception...
if server stop in not manner, the channel i register will stay registered, ...

i dont have much knowledge over remoting or other related matter...
but i checked some of things, and non didnt worked...

the article i went through done registering this way, and didnt unregister the application, and i use it in service, and seem service application host dont close just with service beign stopped...

here's my client class which is used in service applciation...

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp;

namespace Remoting
{
    public class Client
    {
        private RemotableObject remoteObject;

        /// <summary>
        /// Configure Client Class
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="url">Something like: tcp://localhost:8080/HelloWorld</param>
        public Client(string url)
        {
            TcpChannel chan = new TcpChannel();
            ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(chan);

            remoteObject = (RemotableObject)Activator.GetObject(typeof(RemotableObject), url);
        }


        public void SetMessage(string message)
        {
            remoteObject.SetMessage(message);
        }
    }
}
```

as i noticed, the article give no information to the channel, so i'm wonder for unregistering it how should i find it.....

in the server APP, the article done givin host post at last

```
using System.Runtime.Remoting;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp;

namespace Remoting
{
    public abstract class Server:IObserver
    {
        private RemotableObject remotableObject;

        /// <summary>
        /// Configure Server Class
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="port">port number like: 8080</param>
        /// <param name="url">Object url like: HelloWorld</param>
        public Server(int port, string url)
        {
            remotableObject = new RemotableObject();

            TcpChannel channel = new TcpChannel(port);
            ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(channel);
            RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownServiceType(typeof(RemotableObject), url, WellKnownObjectMode.Singleton);

            Cache.Attach(this);
        }

        public abstract void Notify(string message);
    }
}
```

but, even know think i launch my application over a server that run an app with same port number, i do not want to un-register other application channels... what should i do?

BTW most issue is about the client that register a channel, with no information... how do i detect it? and unregister it, before service try to do that, and terminate with exception?

if it help, this is the error i already recieve:

> Event Type: Error
>   Event Source: Event Reader Service
>   Event Category:  None
>   Event ID: 0
>   Date: 8/20/2012
>   Time: 5:23:14 PM
>   User: N/A
>   Computer: HF-SERVER-PC
>   Description:
>   Service cannot be started.
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException: The channel 'tcp' is
>   already registered. at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.ChannelServices.RegisterChannelInternal(IChannel
>   chnl, Boolean ensureSecurity) at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(IChannel
>   chnl) at Remoting.Client..ctor(String url) at
>   FileEventReaderService.Services.Logger.EventLogger..ctor(String
>   source, String logName, String url) at
>   FileEventReaderService.EventReader..ctor(String sqlServer, String
>   instance, String integratedSecurityType, String username, String
>   password, String dataBase) at
>   FileEventReaderService.EventReaderService.OnStart(String[] args) at
>   System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.ServiceQueuedMainCallback(Object
>   state)
>
> For more information, see Help and Support Center at
>   go.microsoft.com/fwlink/….

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case the problem were with multiple registering the tcp channel, in same instance, so i made a singleton class, and just set client once, and all other time i just called that instance....

```
using Remoting;

namespace FileEventReaderService.Services.Remotable
{
    class SingletonClient
    {
        private static SingletonClient _instance = new SingletonClient();
        private Client _client = null;

        public static SingletonClient GetSingletonClient()
        {
            return _instance;
        }

        public Client GetClient()
        {
            return _client;
        }

        public void SetClientConfiguration(string url)
        {
            _client=new Client(url);
        }
    }
}
```

BTW, if any one need to find the process... he can use this article: 
http://www.timvw.be/2007/09/09/build-your-own-netstatexe-with-c/ download the demo source and use it...

i also edit it in my own way, you can use it: (i did not changed 2 main class 'TcpTable' and 'IpHelper')

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Net;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;

namespace FileEventReaderUI.Services.Network
{
    class NetworkInformation
    {
        public ListenerProcessInformation GetListenerProcessInformationByPort(int port)
        {
            string fileName;
            List<string> processModules=new List<string>();

            foreach (TcpRow tcpRow in ManagedIpHelper.GetExtendedTcpTable(true))
            {
                if (tcpRow.LocalEndPoint.Port.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Equals(
                        port.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                    && tcpRow.State==TcpState.Listen)
                {
                    Process process = Process.GetProcessById(tcpRow.ProcessId);
                    if (process.ProcessName != "System")
                    {
                        foreach (ProcessModule processModule in process.Modules)
                        {
                            processModules.Add(processModule.FileName);
                        }

                        fileName = Path.GetFileName(process.MainModule.FileName);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Console.WriteLine("  -- unknown component(s) --"); ProcessModules count=0
                        //Console.WriteLine("  [{0}]", "System");
                        fileName = "[System]";
                    }

                    return new ListenerProcessInformation(fileName
                                                          , processModules.ToArray()
                                                          , new IPEndPoint(tcpRow.LocalEndPoint.Address,
                                                                         tcpRow.LocalEndPoint.Port)
                                                          , new IPEndPoint(tcpRow.RemoteEndPoint.Address,
                                                                         tcpRow.RemoteEndPoint.Port)
                                                          , tcpRow.ProcessId
                                                          , tcpRow.State);
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    #region Managed IP Helper API

    public class TcpTable : IEnumerable<TcpRow>
    {
        #region Private Fields

        private IEnumerable<TcpRow> tcpRows;

        #endregion

        #region Constructors

        public TcpTable(IEnumerable<TcpRow> tcpRows)
        {
            this.tcpRows = tcpRows;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Public Properties

        public IEnumerable<TcpRow> Rows
        {
            get { return this.tcpRows; }
        }

        #endregion

        #region IEnumerable<TcpRow> Members

        public IEnumerator<TcpRow> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return this.tcpRows.GetEnumerator();
        }

        #endregion

        #region IEnumerable Members

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return this.tcpRows.GetEnumerator();
        }

        #endregion
    }

    public class TcpRow
    {
        #region Private Fields

        private IPEndPoint localEndPoint;
        private IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint;
        private TcpState state;
        private int processId;

        #endregion

        #region Constructors

        public TcpRow(IpHelper.TcpRow tcpRow)
        {
            this.state = tcpRow.state;
            this.processId = tcpRow.owningPid;

            int localPort = (tcpRow.localPort1 << 8) + (tcpRow.localPort2) + (tcpRow.localPort3 << 24) + (tcpRow.localPort4 << 16);
            long localAddress = tcpRow.localAddr;
            this.localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(localAddress, localPort);

            int remotePort = (tcpRow.remotePort1 << 8) + (tcpRow.remotePort2) + (tcpRow.remotePort3 << 24) + (tcpRow.remotePort4 << 16);
            long remoteAddress = tcpRow.remoteAddr;
            this.remoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(remoteAddress, remotePort);
        }

        #endregion

        #region Public Properties

        public IPEndPoint LocalEndPoint
        {
            get { return this.localEndPoint; }
        }

        public IPEndPoint RemoteEndPoint
        {
            get { return this.remoteEndPoint; }
        }

        public TcpState State
        {
            get { return this.state; }
        }

        public int ProcessId
        {
            get { return this.processId; }
        }

        #endregion
    }

    public static class ManagedIpHelper
    {
        #region Public Methods

        public static TcpTable GetExtendedTcpTable(bool sorted)
        {
            List<TcpRow> tcpRows = new List<TcpRow>();

            IntPtr tcpTable = IntPtr.Zero;
            int tcpTableLength = 0;

            if (IpHelper.GetExtendedTcpTable(tcpTable, ref tcpTableLength, sorted, IpHelper.AfInet, IpHelper.TcpTableType.OwnerPidAll, 0) != 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    tcpTable = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(tcpTableLength);
                    if (IpHelper.GetExtendedTcpTable(tcpTable, ref tcpTableLength, true, IpHelper.AfInet, IpHelper.TcpTableType.OwnerPidAll, 0) == 0)
                    {
                        IpHelper.TcpTable table = (IpHelper.TcpTable)Marshal.PtrToStructure(tcpTable, typeof(IpHelper.TcpTable));

                        IntPtr rowPtr = (IntPtr)((long)tcpTable + Marshal.SizeOf(table.length));
                        for (int i = 0; i < table.length; ++i)
                        {
                            tcpRows.Add(new TcpRow((IpHelper.TcpRow)Marshal.PtrToStructure(rowPtr, typeof(IpHelper.TcpRow))));
                            rowPtr = (IntPtr)((long)rowPtr + Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(IpHelper.TcpRow)));
                        }
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (tcpTable != IntPtr.Zero)
                    {
                        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(tcpTable);
                    }
                }
            }

            return new TcpTable(tcpRows);
        }

        #endregion
    }

    #endregion

    #region P/Invoke IP Helper API

    /// <summary>
    /// <see cref="http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366073.aspx"/>
    /// </summary>
    public static class IpHelper
    {
        #region Public Fields

        public const string DllName = "iphlpapi.dll";
        public const int AfInet = 2;

        #endregion

        #region Public Methods

        /// <summary>
        /// <see cref="http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365928.aspx"/>
        /// </summary>
        [DllImport(IpHelper.DllName, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern uint GetExtendedTcpTable(IntPtr tcpTable, ref int tcpTableLength, bool sort, int ipVersion, TcpTableType tcpTableType, int reserved);

        #endregion

        #region Public Enums

        /// <summary>
        /// <see cref="http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366386.aspx"/>
        /// </summary>
        public enum TcpTableType
        {
            BasicListener,
            BasicConnections,
            BasicAll,
            OwnerPidListener,
            OwnerPidConnections,
            OwnerPidAll,
            OwnerModuleListener,
            OwnerModuleConnections,
            OwnerModuleAll,
        }

        #endregion

        #region Public Structs

        /// <summary>
        /// <see cref="http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366921.aspx"/>
        /// </summary>
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct TcpTable
        {
            public uint length;
            public TcpRow row;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// <see cref="http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366913.aspx"/>
        /// </summary>
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct TcpRow
        {
            public TcpState state;
            public uint localAddr;
            public byte localPort1;
            public byte localPort2;
            public byte localPort3;
            public byte localPort4;
            public uint remoteAddr;
            public byte remotePort1;
            public byte remotePort2;
            public byte remotePort3;
            public byte remotePort4;
            public int owningPid;
        }

        #endregion
    }

    #endregion
}
```

and the Entity class i use to fill ...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Text;

namespace FileEventReaderUI.Services.Network
{
    class ListenerProcessInformation
    {
        private string _fileName;
        private string[] _processModules;
        private IPEndPoint _localEndPoint;
        private IPEndPoint _remoteEndPoint;
        private int _processId;
        private TcpState _state;

        public ListenerProcessInformation(string fileName, string[] processModules, IPEndPoint localEndPoint, IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint, int processId, TcpState state)
        {
            _fileName = fileName;
            _processModules = processModules;
            _localEndPoint = localEndPoint;
            _remoteEndPoint = remoteEndPoint;
            _processId = processId;
            _state = state;
        }

        public string FileName
        {
            get { return _fileName; }
        }

        public string[] ProcessModules
        {
            get { return _processModules; }
        }

        public IPEndPoint LocalEndPoint
        {
            get { return _localEndPoint; }
        }

        public IPEndPoint RemoteEndPoint
        {
            get { return _remoteEndPoint; }
        }

        public int ProcessId
        {
            get { return _processId; }
        }

        public TcpState State
        {
            get { return _state; }
        }
    }
}
```